# Evernote SCIM API - Password reset

Tags: evernote

I can update the user attributes like userName, familyName, givenName, formatted, active and displayName using API [Method=PUT , URL=https:///scim/v2/] and I tried to do the same with the password attribute , It responds with status [200 - OK] , but the user's password is not updated.

Is there any other API is available for password reset?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing GET request on `/v2/ServiceProviderConfig` and looking for the returned data. `changePassword.supported` should be `false`, which will confirm that changing password is not supported.

Now, SCIM is supposed to be only available when Single Sign On (SSO) is enabled on a business account ([see this Help Center article](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010419308-How-to-configure-SCIM-with-your-Evernote-Business-account)). This means that users sign in using the SSO provider and are not supposed to have any Evernote-specific passwords. It's SSO provider that needs to take care about password management.